# Sail.js how to do association

Tags: node.js, sails.js

I'm new with sails and I heard that v.0.10 supports association. Can anyone provide example for each type of association?

I've tried a simple 1 to many relationship but I'm getting

'Cannot read property \'associations\' of undefined'

Thanks guys

Comment: Current docs for Waterline associations are [here](https://github.com/balderdashy/sails-docs/blob/master/reference/ModelAssociations.md)

Comment: Thanks Scott and just want to say thanks for all your hard work with this great framework. :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Check out the following documentation: [waterline-docs#associations](https://github.com/balderdashy/waterline-docs/blob/master/models/associations).

They will explain in detail how One-to-Many associations work in sails.js

Comment: Waterline documentation has changed,
Please check this link https://github.com/balderdashy/waterline-docs/tree/master/models/associations

Comment: Thanks @Luna for the link!